# Go XML chardata prints empty line

Tags: xml, go, struct

I have a basic xml field which looks like this `<cpe test="123">cpe:/a:openbsd:openssh:5.3p1</cpe>` and I want to unmarshal it using Go. I create the object and while it normally unmarshals and prints the test attribute, the content inside the brackets is always printed as empty.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Cpe struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"cpe"`
    Value   string   `xml:"chardata"`
    Res string   `xml:"test,attr"`
}

func main() {

    var inputXML = `<cpe test="123">cpe:/a:openbsd:openssh:5.3p1</cpe>`

    byteValue := []byte(inputXML)
    
    // Create the onject
    var cpe Cpe
    
    // Unmarshal the xml using the Address object
    xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &cpe)
    
    // prints the Res and Address Value
    fmt.Println(cpe.Res)
    fmt.Println(cpe.Value)  
}
```

The output of those things are `123` and `nothing`. By googling I find out that I can use `innerXML` instead of `chardata`, which had the same result.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/7eyoXjnOlS4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chardata` is an *option* and not an XML tag or attribute name, so you have to put a comma before it if you just specify an option:

```
Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
```

Also do check errors:

```
// Unmarshal the xml using the Address object
err := xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &cpe)
fmt.Println("err:", err)

// prints the Res and Address Value
fmt.Println("attribute:", cpe.Res)
fmt.Println("chardata:", cpe.Value)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tLSqoScrYXf)):

```
err: <nil>
attribute: 123
chardata: cpe:/a:openbsd:openssh:5.3p1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent like 3 hours with this demon.